# Bootsrap 4 - Accordion not working on hover/as expected on hover

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

I am trying to convert bootastap 4 accordion on hover and yes I did but exactly not working as expected.

here is  my code

```
$('.accordion .card-header button').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( '.accordion .card' ).children('.collapse' ).collapse('show');
})
```

and here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywXzjL)

Comment: try this `
$('.accordion .card-header button').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
            $(this).parent().parent().next('div').collapse('show');
        })`

Comment: @tphobe9312 will you please elaborate what I have done worng because your answer seems to work

Comment: u were not using `this`

Comment: @tphobe9312 thanks for telling my mistake so stupid I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a less verbose approach...

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).parents('.card').find('.collapse').collapse('show');
})
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/RNuEV348SQ